# How to format for two column research question?

Tags: tables, two-column

I see in many research paper, the research questions are formatted nicely. I tried to do this with a table that does not work.

What feature they are using this case?

[image]

Comment: \begin{itemize}\item[\bfseries RQ1][Bla bla] Bla bla ... \end{itemize}

Comment: @Fran it is working but how? itemize is for listing items and bfseris is for making font bold. But somehow it seems to also handle indentation. How it is working?

Comment: A  brackets before an `\item` is an optional argument that simply replace the bullet. However the second bracects (the  "[Bla Bla]")   is plain text that is printed as is, and  indented as any text after  `\item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a customized `enumerate`-like list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{researchquestions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[researchquestions]{label*=\textbf{RQ\arabic*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{researchquestions}
\item{} [Repairability] \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{researchquestions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works, what doest it do? label*=\textbf{RQ\arabic*}

Comment: why we need the {} in the first item `\item{}` just trying to understand the solution rather than blindly copying. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\textbf` makes sure, the label part is bold, `RQ` adds "RQ" to each label, `\arabic*` returns the number. If you also want to add the dot after the number, use `label*=\textbf{RQ\arabic*.}` instead.

Comment: The set of `{}` in the first example is because the following word is inside a set of `[]`. If you omit the set of `{}`here, the word inside of `[]` is interpreted as an optional argument of the `\item` command.